# Deploying first Django project

Tags: django

I run a small VPS with 512M memory of memory that currently hosts 3 very low traffic PHP sites and a personal email account.

I have been teaching myself Django over the last few weeks and am starting to think about deploying a project.

There seem to be a very large number of methods for deploying a Django site. Given the limited resources I have available, what would be the most appropriate option?

Will the VPS be suitable to host both python and PHP sites or would it be worth getting a separate server?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you're running on it. If you were running facebook it would probably go down:P If you're using it for small projects it will probably be ok. Try it out and see:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't really a great number of ways to do it. In fact, there's the recommended way - via Apache/mod_wsgi - and all the other ways. The recommended way is fully documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/).

For a low-traffic site, you should have no trouble fitting it in your 512MB VPS along with your PHP sites.

Answer (score 1):

Django has documentation describing possible [server arrangements](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ServerArrangements). For light weight, yet very robust set up, I'd recommend Nginx setup. It's much lighter than Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I run several low-traffic Django sites on a 256 VPS without problem. I have Nginx setup as a reverse proxy and to serve static files (javascript, CSS, images) and Apache using mod_wsgi for serving Django as described in the documentation.

Running PHP sites as well may add a little overhead, but, if you're talking about low-traffic "fun" sites then you should be fine.